# Transformed body fixed-position div aligning to body, not window

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-position

I have created a `<div>` fixed, set the following styles on it:

```
#mydiv {
    position: fixed;
    left: -150px;
    width: 150px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

This produces a `<div>` that is offscreen, and *presumably* the same height as the window.

Then I apply the following styles to the `<body>`:

```
body {
    -webkit-transform: translate(150px, 0);
}
```

To my knowledge, this should move the body `150px` to the right, thereby moving `#mydiv` into view. This works, but now `#mydiv` is the height of the body, not the height of the window.

[Here's a JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyblalock/PTJ42/2/)

Is this a Webkit bug? Or is this something I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

This appears to happen on Firefox as well.

Comment: I don't know why but the cause seems to be the `transform` property you're applying.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem, while perhaps not immediately intuitive, is pretty straightforward.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Normally `position: fixed` elements are aligned relative to the `window` (the parent of the `html` element). When css transforms are applied, however, `position: fixed` elements are aligned relative to the closest parent with a css transform applied.

The alternate approach Webkit and other browsers could have taken, would be to still align `position: fixed` elements to the `window`. But the problem with this would be the `position: fixed` div would not move at all when the body was transformed, and so the div would still be positioned offscreen.